# How to change '0 days 00:00:07.950855000' string format to seconds in SQL

Tags: sql, string, date-formatting

I would like to change the following format to seconds and hours with using SQL.

```
For instance:
0 days 00:00:07.950855000
0 days 00:00:17.368890000
```

The data are stored in hive and I am going to preprocess the data with using the pyspark.

Here is schema:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlgfP.png)

Comment: this part `00:00:07.950855000` is `hours:minutes:seconds` ?

Comment: hours:minutes:seconds:miliseconds

Comment: What is your database ? What is the data type of the column you are storing this in now ? Also please show us how should your result look like from this two examples ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python`?

Comment: @sk306 there's only two colons, and it's nanoseconds.  You are probably going to have to use a regex to parse it.  If you truncate from nanoseconds -> microseconds you can parse the part after days in Python with `time.strptime("00:00:17.368890", "%H:%M:%S.%f")` (from the two examples it looks like maybe the data started as ms precision anyway since last digits are `000` in both cases)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the DBMS (whose tag you did not supply), and the interval being less than one day, it often suffices to hard-cast day-to-second interval (that's what your input is) to a TIME(0) - a time type with no second fractions:

```
WITH
indata(s) AS (
          SELECT INTERVAL  '0 days 00:00:07.950855000'
UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL  '0 days 00:00:17.368890000'
)
SELECT CAST(s AS TIME(0)) AS casttime FROM indata;
-- out  casttime 
-- out ----------
-- out  00:00:08
-- out  00:00:17
```

If that does not work for you: What's your SQL dialect / Your DBMS?